# Swift function returning wrong output

Tags: ios, swift

I created a function that prints where the students are - lesson, long break or short break (and which short break)

Function parameters are:

```
    shortBreak - duration of short break
    longBreak - duration of long break
    lesson - after which lesson is long break
    time - the time where students are located
```

My parameters to test function are

```
   currently(shortBreak: 5, longBreak: 15, lesson: 3, time: "10:37)
```

So it should be

```
  8:00 - 8:45 - lesson
  8:45 - 8:50 - short break
  8:50 - 9:35 - lesson
  9:35 - 9:40 - short break
  9:40 - 10:25 - lesson
  10:25 - 10:40 - long break (after 3.lesson is long break)
```

which means that students are currenty on long break, but my output says that they are on lesson.

I've reviewed the code again, but I can't find where I'm wrong.

Also, is there better way to manipulate with time paramater?

```
import UIKit

enum current {

case lesson
case shortBreak
case longBreak

}

func currently(shortBreak: Int, longBreak: Int, lesson: Int, time:String){

    var shortBreakCounter: Int = 0
    var currentLesson: Int = 1
    var currentHours: Int = 8
    var currentMinute: Int = 0
    var currentCase: current = .lesson


    let minute: Int = Int(time.suffix(2)) ?? 0
    let hour: Int = Int(time.prefix(2)) ?? 0

    if(checkValid(hour: hour, minute: minute)){
    
        print("Invalid time")
    }

    else {
  
        while isInRange(hour: currentHours, minute: currentMinute) {
    
            currentCase = .lesson
    
            currentMinute += 45
    
            if currentMinute >= 60 {
                currentHours += 1
                currentMinute = 0
            }
    
            if currentLesson == lesson {
            
                currentCase = .longBreak
            
                currentMinute += longBreak
            
                if currentMinute >= 60 {
                    currentHours += 1
                    currentMinute = 0
                }
            
            } else{
              
                currentCase = .shortBreak
            
                currentMinute += shortBreak
            
                shortBreakCounter += 1
            
                if currentMinute >= 60 {
                    currentHours += 1
                    currentMinute = 0
                }
            
            }
        
            currentLesson += 1
    
        }

        switch currentCase {
    
            case .shortBreak:
                print("Students are on \(shortBreakCounter) short break")
            case .longBreak:
                print("Students are on long break")
            default:
                print("Students are on lesson")
            }
  
    }

}

func checkValid(hour: Int, minute:Int) -> Bool {

    if hour >= 16 || hour < 8 {
    
        return true
    
    } else if minute > 59 || minute < 0 {
     
        return true
    }

    return false

}

func isInRange(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> Bool{

    if 8..<16 ~= hour &&  0..<60 ~= minute  {
    
        return false

    }

        return true

    }

    currently(shortBreak: 5, longBreak: 15, lesson: 3, time: "10:37")
```

Comment: `currently(shortBreak: 5, longBreak: 15, lesson: 3, time: "10:37)`, how can you conclude that this is a long break? Please explain that as part of the question.

Comment: This looks very fragile, I would look into creating some custom type(s) to hold the data and logic. Like some kind of Schema struct consisting of a collection of another type or just a custom type with start time, duration etc that is linked together to a chain like a linked list

Answer (score 1):

```
if currentMinute >= 60 {
    currentHours += 1
    currentMinute = 0
}
```

This is wrong, you should set `currentMinute` to the current value - 60.

Imagine if the value is 75, there are 15 minutes that is gone because you set it as 0.

it should be

```
if currentMinute >= 60 {
    currentHours += 1
    currentMinute = currentMinute - 60
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isInRange always returns false if checkValid is true. You are always getting the default currentCase (lesson).

A better way to "edit the time parameter" is by using Date.